# How to do a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu. If I select the **home 1** I want to show **HOME1** options. If select **home2** option I want to show **HOME2** and hide **HOME1** option. **Select Category** Should display every time. Here I was try a code. But it was not working. Please help to do this. Thank You.

```js
$('.home1').on('click', function() {
  $('.homes').hide();
  $('#HOME1').show();
});

$('.home2').on('click', function() {
  $('.homes').hide();
  $('#HOME2').show();
});
```

```css
.homes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Home Page</label>
  <select class="form-control category">
    <option>Select Home Page</option>
    <option class="home1">Home 1</option>
    <option class="home2">Home 2</option>
    <option class="home3">Home 3</option>
    <option class="home4">Home 4</option>
    <option class="home5">home 5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group homes" id="HOME1">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Category</label>
  <select class="form-control category">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <option>Slider</option>
    <option>Company Details</option>
    <option>Why Us</option>
    <option>Client Estimonials</option>
    <option>New Projects</option>
    <option>Latest News</option>
    <option>Our Clients</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group homes" id="HOME2">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Category</label>
  <select class="form-control category">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <option>Slider</option>
    <option>Company Details</option>
    <option>Why Us</option>
    <option>Client Estimonials</option>
    <option>New Projects</option>
    <option>Latest News</option>
    <option>Our Clients</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead try to add change event on select and process accoudingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.category').on('change', function() {
  $('.homes').hide();
  $('#' + $(this)[0].selectedOptions[0].className).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.homes {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Home Page</label>
      <select class="form-control category">
        <option>Select Home Page</option>
        <option class="home1">Home 1</option>
        <option class="home2">Home 2</option>
        <option class="home3">Home 3</option>
        <option class="home4">Home 4</option>
        <option class="home5">home 5</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group homes" id="home1">
    <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Category</label>
      <select class="form-control category">
        <option>Select Category</option>
        <option>Slider</option>
        <option>Company Details</option>
        <option>Why Us</option>
        <option>Client Estimonials</option>
        <option>New Projects</option>
        <option>Latest News</option>
        <option>Our Clients</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group homes" id="home2">
    <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Category</label>
      <select class="form-control category">
        <option>Select Category</option>
        <option>Slider</option>
        <option>Company Details</option>
        <option>Why Us</option>
        <option>Client Estimonials</option>
        <option>New Projects</option>
        <option>Latest News</option>
        <option>Our Clients</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this)[0]` you can try `$(this).get()`

Answer (score 2):

### Restructuring

I'd recommend restructuring your HTML and jQuery to increase functionality and readability.  I would make the id's the same as the value that is outputted from the select that way you can append it.  Additionally, you need to distinguish between the first select and the other two, that way you don't incorrectly hide items.

### New Code

```js
$('#main').on('change', function() {
  $('.homes').hide();
  $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
.homes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Home Page</label>
  <select class="form-control category" id="main">
    <option>Select Home Page</option>
    <option value="home1">Home 1</option>
    <option value="home2">Home 2</option>
    <option value="home3">Home 3</option>
    <option value="home4">Home 4</option>
    <option value="home5">home 5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group homes" id="home1">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Category</label>
  <select class="form-control category">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <option>Slider</option>
    <option>Company Details</option>
    <option>Why Us</option>
    <option>Client Estimonials</option>
    <option>New Projects</option>
    <option>Latest News</option>
    <option>Our Clients</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group homes" id="home2">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Category</label>
  <select class="form-control category">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <option>Slider</option>
    <option>Company Details</option>
    <option>Why Us</option>
    <option>Client Estimonials</option>
    <option>New Projects</option>
    <option>Latest News</option>
    <option>Our Clients</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check snippet below:

```js
$('.names.category').on('change', function(event) {
  $('.homes').hide()
  $('#' + event.target.value).show()
});
```

```css
.homes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Home Page</label>
  <select class="form-control names category">
  <option>Select Home Page</option>
  <option value="HOME1">Home 1</option>
  <option value="HOME2">Home 2</option>
  <option value="HOME3">Home 3</option>
  <option value="HOME4">Home 4</option>
  <option value="HOME5">home 5</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group homes" id="HOME1">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Category</label>
  <select class="form-control category">
         <option>Select Category</option>
         <option>Slider</option>
  <option>Company Details</option>
  <option>Why Us</option>
  <option>Client Estimonials</option>
  <option>New Projects</option>
  <option>Latest News</option>
  <option>Our Clients</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group homes" id="HOME2">
  <label class="names" for="exampleInputName2">Category</label>
  <select class="form-control category">
  <option>Select Category</option>
  <option>Slider</option>
  <option>Company Details</option>
  <option>Why Us</option>
  <option>Client Estimonials</option>
  <option>New Projects</option>
  <option>Latest News</option>
  <option>Our Clients</option>
 </select>
</div>
```